# Gensim: Not able to load the id2word file

Tags: nlp, gensim, topic-modeling

I am working on topic inference on a new corpus given a previously derived lda model. I am able to load the model perfectly, while I am not able to load the id2word file to create the `corpora.Dictionary` object needed to map the new corpus into numbers: the `load` method returns a dict attribute error that I don't know why. Below is the minimal code that replicates the situation, and I have attached the code (and packages used) here.

Thank you in advance for your response...

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import gensim
from gensim import corpora
import datetime
import nltk

model_name = "lda_sub_full_35"

dictionary_name = "lda_sub_full_35.id2word"

model_for_inference = gensim.models.LdaModel.load(model_name, mmap='r')
print('Successfully load the model')
lda_dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load(dictionary_name, mmap='r')
```

I expect to have both the dictionary and the model loaded, but it turns out that when I load the dictionary, I got the below error:

````
File "topic_inference.py", line 31, in <module>
    lda_dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load(dictionary_name, mmap='r')
File "/topic_modeling/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 487, in load
    obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_load_specials'```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How were the contents of the `lda_sub_full_35.id2word` file originally saved?

Only if it was saved by a Gensim `corpora.Dictionary` object's `.save()` method should it be loaded as you've tried, with `corpora.Dictionary.load()`.

If, by any chance, it was just a plain Python `dict` saved via some other method of writing a `pickle()`-created object, then you would need to load it in a symmetrically-matched way. That might be as simple as:

```py
import pickle

with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    lda_dictionary = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I save id2word as a dict during the lda process...